# Determine f ' (0) Using the First Principles Definition of the Derivative

Tags: calculus

Determine $f'(0)$ Using the First Principles Definition of the Derivative.

$$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R\\
x \mapsto  \begin{cases}x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}); & x \neq 0\\
    0; & x = 0.\end{cases}
$$
My workings:

$$\begin{align}
f'(a) &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0 + h) - 0}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} h\sin(\frac{1}{h}) = 0  &\text{By the squeeze theorem.}
\end{align}$$

Please post your solution and full workings below.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Don't post images of text. Type out the question. 2. Don't post questions without showing any of your own work.

Comment: Sorry. I am unfamiliar with MathJax and didn't want to type out a ton of garbage for people :(

Comment: Not an excuse. At all. Look, if you post an image of a text, that makes it harder to read on various devices, and also makes it impossible for search engines to find your question. On the other hand, if you type it out (even if you do it badly), someone will edit and repair what you did wrong. Then, you can look at the edit and learn what you could have done better.

Comment: I did what I could to fix it up. It looks worse but hopefully its more acceptable.

Comment: It "looks worse", but it was easier for me to fix than before. It now looks better.

Comment: Thank you for fixing it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, I would just add a line or two about how you know that

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \left[h\sin\left(\frac1h\right)\right]=0$$

Comment: Sorry again. I added it and it looks horrible. :( I am working on my MathJax, don't worry. Anyway, we know this by using the squeeze theorem, right?

Comment: @ThePointer Correct. But maybe just invoking the theorem isn't enough. It would be better to say "because $|h\sin\left(\frac1h\right)| < |h|$, we can apply the squeeze theorem and show that the limit is $0$".